# Cannot play this video when converting format to .mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am converting video to .mp4 format, but when i convert video using ffmpeg using the following command:

```
exec('D:\wamp\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -i D:/wamp/www/upload_google_drive/output.flv -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset slow -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -ac 2 D:/wamp/www/upload_google_drive/w3.mp4 2>&1',$output);
```

in some of the devices it does not run. The message which appears is

> Cannot play this video.

Please help to sort out my issue.

Output:

```
     Array ( [0] => ffmpeg version N-77137-gff6dd58 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers [1] => built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC) 
    [2] => configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib 
    [3] => libavutil 55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100 
    [4] => libavcodec 57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100 
    [5] => libavformat 57. 19.100 / 57. 19.100 
    [6] => libavdevice 57. 0.100 / 57. 0.100 
    [7] => libavfilter 6. 20.100 / 6. 20.100 
    [8] => libswscale 4. 0.100 / 4. 0.100 
    [9] => libswresample 2. 0.101 / 2. 0.101 
    [10] => libpostproc 54. 0.100 / 54. 0.100 
    [11] => Input #0, flv, from 'D:/wamp/www/upload_google_drive/output.flv': 
    [12] => Metadata: 
    [13] => major_brand : mp42 
    [14] => minor_version : 1 
    [15] => compatible_brands: mp42avc1 
    [16] => encoder : Lavf57.19.100 
    [17] => Duration: 00:01:00.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 307 kb/s 
    [18] => Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 480x320, 200 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc 
    [19] => Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 62 kb/s 
    [20] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 

[21] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0 [22] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=umh subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=50 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=19.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00 
[23] => Output #0, mp4, to 'D:/wamp/www/upload_google_drive/w5.mp4': 
[24] => Metadata: 
[25] => major_brand : mp42 
[26] => minor_version : 1 
[27] => compatible_brands: mp42avc1 
[28] => encoder : Lavf57.19.100 
[29] => Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 480x320, q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc 
[30] => Metadata: 
[31] => encoder : Lavc57.17.100 libx264 
[32] => Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s 
[33] => Metadata: 
[34] => encoder : Lavc57.17.100 aac 
[35] => Stream mapping: 
[36] => Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flv1 (flv) -> h264 (libx264)) 
[37] => Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native)) 
[38] => Press [q] to stop, [?] for help 
[39] => frame= 55 fps=0.0 q=23.0 size= 27kB time=00:00:02.22 bitrate= 98.2kbits/s frame= 96 fps= 93 q=24.0 size= 137kB time=00:00:03.92 bitrate= 285.4kbits/s frame= 161 fps=105 q=24.0 size= 317kB time=00:00:06.64 bitrate= 391.6kbits/s frame= 220 fps=108 q=24.0 size= 541kB time=00:00:09.07 bitrate= 487.8kbits/s frame= 274 fps=108 q=24.0 size= 773kB time=00:00:11.35 bitrate= 557.8kbits/s frame= 326 fps=107 q=24.0 size= 1109kB time=00:00:13.53 bitrate= 671.4kbits/s Past duration 0.607994 too large 
[40] => Last message repeated 1 times 
[41] => Past duration 0.615990 too large 
[42] => Past duration 0.607994 too large 
[43] => frame= 382 fps=108 q=24.0 size= 1439kB time=00:00:15.81 bitrate= 745.6kbits/s Past duration 0.615990 too large 
[44] => Past duration 0.607994 too large 
[45] => Past duration 0.623985 too large 
[46] => Past duration 0.615990 too large 
[47] => Past duration 0.607994 too large
[48] => Past duration 0.623985 too large 
[49] => Past duration 0.615990 too large 
[50] => Past duration 0.631996 too large 
[51] => Past duration 0.623985 too large 
[52] => Past duration 0.615990 too large 
[53] => Past duration 0.631996 too large 
[54] => Past duration 0.623985 too large 
[55] => Past duration 0.639992 too large
[56] => Past duration 0.631996 too large 
[57] => Past duration 0.623985 too large 
[58] => Past duration 0.639992 too large 
[59] => Past duration 0.631996 too large
[60] => Past duration 0.647987 too large 
[61] => Past duration 0.639992 too large 
[62] => Past duration 0.631996 too large 
[63] => Past duration 0.647987 too large 
[64] => Past duration 0.639992 too large 
[65] => Past duration 0.655998 too large 
[66] => Past duration 0.647987 too large 
[67] => Past duration 0.639992 too large 
[68] => Past duration 0.655998 too large 
[69] => Past duration 0.647987 too large 
[70] => Past duration 0.663994 too large 
[71] => Past duration 0.655998 too large 
[72] => Past duration 0.647987 too large 
[73] => Past duration 0.663994 too large 
[74] => Past duration 0.655998 too large 
[75] => Past duration 0.671989 too large 
[76] => Past duration 0.663994 too large
[77] => Past duration 0.655998 too large 
[78] => Past duration 0.671989 too large 
[79] => Past duration 0.663994 too large 
[80] => Past duration 0.679985 too large 
[81] => Past duration 0.671989 too large 
[82] => Past duration 0.663994 too large 
[83] => Past duration 0.679985 too large 
[84] => Past duration 0.671989 too large 
[85] => Past duration 0.687996 too large 
[86] => Past duration 0.679985 too large 
[87] => Past duration 0.671989 too large 
[88] => Past duration 0.687996 too large 
[89] => Past duration 0.679985 too large 
[90] => Past duration 0.695992 too large 
[91] => Past duration 0.687996 too large 
[92] => Past duration 0.679985 too large 
[93] => Past duration 0.695992 too large 
[94] => Past duration 0.687996 too large 
[95] => Past duration 0.703987 too large 
[96] => Past duration 0.695992 too large 
[97] => frame= 436 fps=108 q=24.0 size= 1732kB time=00:00:18.08 bitrate= 784.5kbits/s Past duration 0.687996 too large 
[98] => Past duration 0.703987 too large 
[99] => Past duration 0.695992 too large 
[100] => Past duration 0.711998 too large 
[101] => Past duration 0.703987 too large 
[102] => Past duration 0.695992 too large 
[103] => Past duration 0.711998 too large 
[104] => Past duration 0.703987 too large 
[105] => Past duration 0.719994 too large 
[106] => Past duration 0.711998 too large 
[107] => Past duration 0.703987 too large 
[108] => Past duration 0.719994 too large 
[109] => Past duration 0.711998 too large 
[110] => Past duration 0.727989 too large 
[111] => Past duration 0.719994 too large 
[112] => Past duration 0.711998 too large 
[113] => Past duration 0.727989 too large 
[114] => Past duration 0.719994 too large 
[115] => Past duration 0.735985 too large 
[116] => Past duration 0.727989 too large 
[117] => Past duration 0.719994 too large 
[118] => Past duration 0.735985 too large 
[119] => Past duration 0.727989 too large 
[120] => Past duration 0.743996 too large 
[121] => Past duration 0.735985 too large 
[122] => Past duration 0.727989 too large 
[123] => Past duration 0.743996 too large 
[124] => Past duration 0.735985 too large 
[125] => Past duration 0.751991 too large 
[126] => Past duration 0.743996 too large 
[127] => Past duration 0.735985 too large 
[128] => Past duration 0.751991 too large 
[129] => Past duration 0.743996 too large 
[130] => Past duration 0.759987 too large 
[131] => Past duration 0.751991 too large 
[132] => Past duration 0.743996 too large 
[133] => Past duration 0.759987 too large 
[134] => Past duration 0.751991 too large 
[135] => Past duration 0.767998 too large 
[136] => Past duration 0.759987 too large 
[137] => Past duration 0.751991 too large 
[138] => Past duration 0.767998 too large 
[139] => Past duration 0.759987 too large 
[140] => Past duration 0.775993 too large 
[141] => Past duration 0.767998 too large 
[142] => Past duration 0.759987 too large 
[143] => Past duration 0.775993 too large 
[144] => Past duration 0.767998 too large 
[145] => Past duration 0.783989 too large 
[146] => Past duration 0.775993 too large 
[147] => Past duration 0.767998 too large 
[148] => Past duration 0.783989 too large 
[149] => Past duration 0.775993 too large 
[150] => Past duration 0.792000 too large 
[151] => Past duration 0.783989 too large 
[152] => Past duration 0.775993 too large 
[153] => Past duration 0.792000 too large 
[154] => Past duration 0.783989 too large 
[155] => Past duration 0.799995 too large 
[156] => Past duration 0.792000 too large 
[157] => Past duration 0.783989 too large 
[158] => Past duration 0.799995 too large 
[159] => Past duration 0.792000 too large 
[160] => Past duration 0.807991 too large 
[161] => Past duration 0.799995 too large 
[162] => Past duration 0.792000 too large 
[163] => Past duration 0.807991 too large 
[164] => Past duration 0.799995 too large 
[165] => Past duration 0.815987 too large 
[166] => Past duration 0.807991 too large 
[167] => Past duration 0.799995 too large 
[168] => Past duration 0.815987 too large 
[169] => frame= 508 fps=112 q=24.0 size= 1953kB time=00:00:21.10 bitrate= 758.1kbits/s Past duration 0.807991 too large 
[170] => Past duration 0.823997 too large 
[171] => Past duration 0.815987 too large 
[172] => Past duration 0.807991 too large 
[173] => Past duration 0.823997 too large 
[174] => Past duration 0.815987 too large 
[175] => Past duration 0.831993 too large 
[176] => Past duration 0.823997 too large 
[177] => Past duration 0.815987 too large 
[178] => Past duration 0.831993 too large 
[179] => Past duration 0.823997 too large 
[180] => Past duration 0.839989 too large 
[181] => Past duration 0.831993 too large 
[182] => Past duration 0.823997 too large 
[183] => Past duration 0.839989 too large 
[184] => Past duration 0.831993 too large 
[185] => Past duration 0.848000 too large 
[186] => Past duration 0.839989 too large 
[187] => Past duration 0.831993 too large 
[188] => Past duration 0.848000 too large 
[189] => Past duration 0.839989 too large 
[190] => Past duration 0.855995 too large 
[191] => Past duration 0.848000 too large 
[192] => Past duration 0.839989 too large 
[193] => Past duration 0.855995 too large
[194] => Past duration 0.848000 too large 
[195] => Past duration 0.863991 too large 
[196] => Past duration 0.855995 too large 
[197] => Past duration 0.848000 too large 
[198] => Past duration 0.863991 too large 
[199] => Past duration 0.855995 too large 
[200] => Past duration 0.871986 too large 
[201] => Past duration 0.863991 too large 
[202] => Past duration 0.855995 too large 
[203] => Past duration 0.871986 too large 
[204] => Past duration 0.863991 too large 
[205] => Past duration 0.879997 too large 
[206] => Past duration 0.871986 too large 
[207] => Past duration 0.863991 too large 
[208] => Past duration 0.879997 too large 
[209] => Past duration 0.871986 too large 
[210] => Past duration 0.887993 too large 
[211] => Past duration 0.879997 too large 
[212] => Past duration 0.871986 too large 
[213] => Past duration 0.887993 too large 
[214] => Past duration 0.879997 too large 
[215] => Past duration 0.895988 too large 
[216] => Past duration 0.887993 too large 
[217] => Past duration 0.879997 too large 
[218] => Past duration 0.895988 too large 
[219] => Past duration 0.887993 too large 
[220] => Past duration 0.903999 too large 
[221] => Past duration 0.895988 too large 
[222] => Past duration 0.887993 too large 
[223] => Past duration 0.903999 too large 
[224] => Past duration 0.895988 too large 
[225] => Past duration 0.911995 too large 
[226] => Past duration 0.903999 too large 
[227] => Past duration 0.895988 too large 
[228] => Past duration 0.911995 too large 
[229] => Past duration 0.903999 too large 
[230] => Past duration 0.919991 too large 
[231] => Past duration 0.911995 too large 
[232] => frame= 571 fps=113 q=24.0 size= 2150kB time=00:00:23.68 bitrate= 743.7kbits/s Past duration 0.903999 too large 
[233] => Past duration 0.919991 too large 
[234] => Past duration 0.911995 too large 
[235] => Past duration 0.927986 too large 
[236] => Past duration 0.919991 too large 
[237] => Past duration 0.911995 too large 
[238] => Past duration 0.927986 too large 
[239] => Past duration 0.919991 too large 
[240] => Past duration 0.935997 too large 
[241] => Past duration 0.927986 too large 
[242] => Past duration 0.919991 too large 
[243] => Past duration 0.935997 too large 
[244] => Past duration 0.927986 too large 
[245] => Past duration 0.943993 too large 
[246] => Past duration 0.935997 too large 
[247] => Past duration 0.927986 too large 
[248] => Past duration 0.943993 too large 
[249] => Past duration 0.935997 too large 
[250] => Past duration 0.951988 too large 
[251] => Past duration 0.943993 too large 
[252] => Past duration 0.935997 too large 
[253] => Past duration 0.951988 too large 
[254] => Past duration 0.943993 too large 
[255] => Past duration 0.959999 too large 
[256] => Past duration 0.951988 too large 
[257] => Past duration 0.943993 too large 
[258] => Past duration 0.959999 too large 
[259] => Past duration 0.951988 too large 
[260] => Past duration 0.967995 too large 
[261] => Past duration 0.959999 too large 
[262] => Past duration 0.951988 too large 
[263] => Past duration 0.967995 too large 
[264] => Past duration 0.959999 too large 
[265] => Past duration 0.975990 too large 
[266] => Past duration 0.967995 too large 
[267] => Past duration 0.959999 too large 
[268] => Past duration 0.975990 too large 
[269] => Past duration 0.967995 too large 
[270] => Past duration 0.983986 too large 
[271] => Past duration 0.975990 too large 
[272] => Past duration 0.967995 too large 
[273] => Past duration 0.983986 too large 
[274] => Past duration 0.975990 too large 
[275] => Past duration 0.991997 too large 
[276] => Past duration 0.983986 too large 
[277] => Past duration 0.975990 too large 
[278] => Past duration 0.991997 too large 
[279] => Past duration 0.983986 too large 
[280] => Past duration 0.999992 too large 
[281] => Past duration 0.991997 too large 
[282] => Past duration 0.983986 too large 
[283] => frame= 622 fps=112 q=24.0 size= 2328kB time=00:00:25.82 bitrate= 738.7kbits/s Past duration 0.999992 too large 
[284] => Past duration 0.991997 too large 
[285] => Past duration 0.999992 too large 
[286] => Past duration 0.991997 too large 
[287] => Past duration 0.999992 too large 
[288] => Last message repeated 1 times 
[289] => frame= 672 fps=111 q=24.0 size= 2585kB time=00:00:27.91 bitrate= 758.8kbits/s frame= 719 fps=110 q=24.0 size= 2829kB time=00:00:29.86 bitrate= 776.0kbits/s frame= 765 fps=109 q=24.0 size= 3063kB time=00:00:31.76 bitrate= 789.8kbits/s frame= 812 fps=108 q=24.0 size= 3282kB time=00:00:33.71 bitrate= 797.5kbits/s frame= 853 fps=106 q=24.0 size= 3472kB time=00:00:35.45 bitrate= 802.2kbits/s frame= 897 fps=105 q=24.0 size= 3713kB time=00:00:37.26 bitrate= 816.1kbits/s frame= 943 fps=104 q=24.0 size= 3960kB time=00:00:39.17 bitrate= 828.0kbits/s frame= 987 fps=103 q=24.0 size= 4205kB time=00:00:41.00 bitrate= 840.1kbits/s frame= 1033 fps=102 q=24.0 size= 4442kB time=00:00:42.91 bitrate= 848.1kbits/s frame= 1074 fps=101 q=24.0 size= 4627kB time=00:00:44.60 bitrate= 849.7kbits/s frame= 1123 fps=101 q=24.0 size= 4861kB time=00:00:46.67 bitrate= 853.3kbits/s frame= 1168 fps=101 q=24.0 size= 5079kB time=00:00:48.52 bitrate= 857.3kbits/s frame= 1216 fps=100 q=24.0 size= 5312kB time=00:00:50.52 bitrate= 861.3kbits/s frame= 1254 fps= 99 q=24.0 size= 5519kB time=00:00:52.10 bitrate= 867.7kbits/s frame= 1302 fps= 99 q=24.0 size= 5751kB time=00:00:54.12 bitrate= 870.5kbits/s frame= 1358 fps= 99 q=24.0 size= 6002kB time=00:00:56.47 bitrate= 870.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 frame= 1427 fps=101 q=24.0 size= 6243kB time=00:00:59.35 bitrate= 861.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 frame= 1444 fps=100 q=-1.0 Lsize= 6451kB time=00:01:00.16 bitrate= 878.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 
[290] => video:5008kB audio:1407kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.550038% 
[291] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] frame I:10 Avg QP:13.67 size: 25967 
[292] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] frame P:1434 Avg QP:18.73 size: 3395 
[293] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] mb I I16..4: 36.0% 0.0% 64.0% 
[294] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] mb P I16..4: 3.6% 0.0% 4.0% P16..4: 21.9% 5.5% 4.2% 0.0% 0.0% skip:60.8% 
[295] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 51.3% 62.1% 11.5% inter: 11.4% 14.4% 2.1% 
[296] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] i16 v,h,dc,p: 52% 30% 16% 2% 
[297] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 34% 25% 17% 3% 4% 4% 3% 4% 5% 
[298] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] i8c dc,h,v,p: 39% 32% 25% 4% 
[299] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] ref P L0: 82.2% 8.5% 4.8% 2.2% 2.3% 
[300] => [libx264 @ 0000000001c31860] kb/s:681.85 [301] => [aac @ 0000000001c322a0] Qavg: 14325.964 )
```

Comment: Which devices are these?

Comment: -Maxito - there are some android mobile devices on which video does not support.Please help to solve my issue

Comment: -LordNeckbeard- I have added the output, Please check it.It is not working on somw android devices.

Comment: -LordNeckbeard- Actually it was php code i have formatted it now u can check it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using baseline profile which maximizes compatibility with different devices, including android devices, try adding `-profile:v baseline -level 3.0` to your command.

Refer to this link for more profile compatibility information: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Compatibility

Comment: Thanks Maxito for your answer, but this one is also not working, Conversion is successfull but on some android device it is not working.